# Invalidating caches_action outside of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're currently using caches_action to cache our homepage. When there's an event from an external source, we need to invalidate our cache and regenerate our homepage.

How can we achieve this with caches_action?
If caches_action is not possible, how can we achieve this with Rails caching  mechanism?

Thanks!